# Run Model in Google BigQuery from REST API

Tags: google-bigquery

I am wondering if there is a way to physically run a model deployed on Google BigQuery from the REST API?

The docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/models

Allow for create, amend etc. However, I cannot find a way to run this directly from the API?

Anyone have any insights as everything else runs off the API so I would prefer not to delve off course

Comment: Think I have found a way, Link the Model exec to a job and then use the Job API to execute - going to test and post results

Answer (score 1):

You should use [CREATE MODEL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/bigqueryml-web-ui-start#run_the_create_model_query) query and use BigQuery REST API like [Jobs.Insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) to run it

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, going to set it up and test, i agree that seems to be the way they want us to run them, thanks!

Comment: If Mikhail's answer helped you, please consider accepting and upvoting it :)

Comment: If Mikhail's answer helped you, please consider accepting and upvoting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using the [Jobs.Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) API call, make sure you add the parameter useLegacySql: False or True depending on your use case,
thanks Mikhail for pointing me in the direction